# return object value using json or another convient class

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

The javascript does not get value from the web method.

It says undefined for the value of s located in CallMe()..

My aim is get an object from the web method.... to use the data in js..

What am I missing_?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    Label lblGeneral;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblGeneral = textMessager;
    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ShowMessage()
    {

        return ExternalManager.Write();
    }
}
```

**js**

```
// JScript File
function CallMe()
 {    
     // call server side method
     var s = PageMethods.ShowMessage();
     s = eval(s);
 }



(function() {
var status = true;
var fetchService = function() {

           if(status){
             CallMe();
            status = false;
            }


            setTimeout(fetchService, 5000);
           status = true;

        }

window.onload = fetchService;
}())
```

****The Util Class ******

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ExternalManager
/// </summary>
public class ExternalManager
{
    public ExternalManager()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    public static string Write()
    {
        string s = "Okay Buddy" + DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string serializedPerson = jss.Serialize(s);
        return  s;
    }
}
```

Used Tech:
Asp.net 2.0 + Ajax Enabled
C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an AJAX call. You cannot write:

```
var s = PageMethods.ShowMessage();
```

and expect to use the `s` variable immediately because the call is asynchronous (it returns immediately but the result is available only later after the server responds). You need to use the callback. Here's a full working example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Services" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ShowMessage()
    {
        return "Okay Buddy" + DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString();
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallMe() {
            // call server side method
            PageMethods.ShowMessage(function (result) {
                alert(result);
            });
        }

        (function() {
            var status = true;
            var fetchService = function () {
                if (status) {
                    CallMe();
                    status = false;
                }
                setTimeout(fetchService, 5000);
                status = true;
            }

            window.onload = fetchService;
        }());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also notice that you should not use `JavaScriptSerializer` manually. It is used internally by `PageMethods`. In your `ShowMessage` method you could also return complex objects.

If the method had for example two arguments you would pass them before the success and error callbacks:

```
PageMethods.ShowMessage('param1', 'param2', onSucceed, onError);
```